# How do I increase copy/paste buffer size in Linux

Tags: linux, terminal

I'm trying to copy and paste lines of code to the linux terminal. However, I've noticed that when the copied text is too long (let's say, 60 or more lines), it gets trimmed and altered in an apparently random way (e.g. some characters missing).

I found the same problem in Ubuntu Karmic Koala, Fedora 10 and Ubuntu Jaunty Jackalope.

Any clue why this happens and if I can increase the size of safely copy/paste-able text?

Comment: Try a different terminal?

Is this the terminal launched from the desktop on the machine itself, or are you connecting remotely?

Does the clipboard limit behave the same in the terminal, in other apps, or just your ide/editor within that terminal?

Comment: Tell us what terminal you are using. I have copied and pasted blocks of text thousands of lines long into gnome-terminal and putty with no issues.

Answer (score 2):

You could try messing with the preferences of the terminal. This 60 limit seems more a limit of the terminal, so there's should be an option the increase the terminal buffer.